# C# Remote Desktop Without Routing Issues

Tags: c#, client-server, remote-access, tcpclient, p2p

After using a popular piece of software to remotely access my work computers recently (I own the company - this is all legal...), I've become interested in achieving similar remote desktop functionality in my own C# program, which is currently for hobby purposes but could find a use at work if successful.

I am using TcpClient and TcpListener and have created a server which listens for and accepts connections. Essentially I have a client-server chat system working. Clients all log in to the server initially and use encrypted TCP communications.

For file transfers and screen-shotting, I'd really like the clients to communicate directly (otherwise files have to be sent client --> server --> client). I just wondered if there is a way that commercial software achieves this without end-users having to set up router and firewall rules?

Once both clients have "dialled out" to the server, is there then a way of then obtaining direct client (peer to peer) communications without sending everything to the server first?

I have fibre broadband, so have no bandwidth issues. It just seems a bit of a waste for all my files to make two journeys (especially if the server is remote but the two clients are on a LAN).

Comment: You need to get through the firewall.  No way of bypassing.  You could have a webserver using port 8080 (that is what http uses) and then forward to your TCP port.  This is normally referred to as port forwarding.  You could make your TCP application use port 8080 which can get through firewall.

Comment: Search for the term "hole punching" e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

Comment: CrhFin either 8080 or 80.

Comment: Thank you @thehennyy - I think Hole Punching must be the mechanism I'm looking for, which is going to involve getting hold of the Socket object from TcpClient and doing some lower-level stuff, but seems feasible. At least I know the term to research now. If you want to add an answer, I'm happy to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are searching for is probably "hole punching".

> Hole punching is a technique in computer networking for establishing a direct connection between two parties in which one or both are behind firewalls or behind routers that use network address translation (NAT).
>   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)